# How can I find in SQL all X from one table which have same set of Y values from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, many-to-many, grouping

I have table X, and each record in X has many records in Y.
I want a simple SQL which brings just the records from X which has the same set of records from Y.
Each group of records from X I want it to be distinguished from other group (which has another set of records from Y) with some value.
Example:

```
1 - 5
  - 6
2 - 3
3 - 5
  - 6
4 - 3
5 - 7
```

I want it back as:

```
1 - a
3 - a
2 - b
4 - b
5 - c
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the data?

Comment: i put it in the question

Comment: Where are the items in the first table stored? in a XY table? it seems like this is a many-to-many relationship, not one-to-many. Also where did the a,b,c.. identifiers come from?

Comment: yeah you're right it's many to many. a,b,c are some virtual values used to distinguish the groups. also the records must come ordered by this virtual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a job for [`wm_concat`](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php) or `stragg`, which will give you your unique values without you having to transliterate them to something.

```
select x.id, stragg(x.value)
  from table_x x
 group by x.id
```

And with your comment you can guarantee order in a sub-query:

```
select id, substr(stragg(value),1,10)
  from ( select id, value
           from table_x
          order by id, value )
 group by id
```

The only problem is your values won't be "pretty" they'll be a concatenation of all the possible values you have in `table_x`

```
SQL> create table table_x ( id number, value number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into table_x values (1,5);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_x values (1,6);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_x values (2,3);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_x values (3,6);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_x values (3,5);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_x values (4,3);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into table_x values (5,7);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> select id, substr(stragg(value),1,10)
  2    from ( select id, value
  3             from table_x
  4            order by id, value )
  5   group by id
  6         ;

        ID STRAGG(VALUE)
---------- ----------
         1 5;6
         2 3
         3 5;6
         4 3
         5 7

SQL>
```

Comment: I thought of that, but the strings must be in the same order: 3,5 and 3,5. Not 3,5 and another one in 5,3.

Comment: I will use: select x, LISTAGG(y, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY y) from ... group by x order by 2;

Comment: @CosminVacaroiu, I was just about to suggest ordering in a sub-query. I updated my answer to show that it'd also work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing the problem but won't the INTERSECT operator do this job for you?

```
select a, b from table_x
INTERSECT
select a, b from table_y
```

will return all rows that exist in both tables. (This could also be done with a simple JOIN, but in this case INTERSECT is prettier)